# Deploy Python Script without using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

A Python 2.7 script needs to be deployed on several systems that does not have a internet connection for `pip install`. This script depends on several libraries installed using `pip install`.

How can these packages that are normally installed using `pip` be packaged along with the Python script and be made to run on another system?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the package using a machine with internet with --download option

```
pip install --download <path>
```

copy the contents of the directory to target machine then use

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=<path>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download tar package from PIP and extract it locally. 
You can copy the package directory from the tar and place at the root location of your application.

The other approach is to copy the package directory to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` in CentOS and 
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you download the `packagename.whl` **(for linux, use it's `.tar`)** file of the required package on a machine and copy that file to install it over several machines using `pip -install packagename.whl` **(`.tar` for Linux)** on terminal.

Make sure that file is in the folder where this command is run from.